# move element li into ul with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

i'm looking for a solution to move an element  that i need to move into a

.... im using jquery and i leave here the code i tried with different things but wasn't working it.

this is the big menu

```
 <ul class="sf-menu">

    <li><a href="">Student Centre</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="9">STUDENT CENTRAL WEBSITE</a></li>
        <li><a href="10">STUDENT CENTRAL EMAIL</a></li>
        <li><a href="11">CCM STUDENT SURVIAL TIPS</a></li>
        <li><a href="12">VET TUTTTION ASSURANSE</a></li>
        <li><a href="13">WHAT GOING ON AT CCM</a></li>
        <li><a href="14">IMPORTANT STUDENTS NOTICE</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="">Research</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="_16">WHAT IS HOLISTIC KINESIOLOGY ?</a></li>
        <li><a href="_17">TRANF. CHILDREN W/ LEARNING DIFFICULTIES</a></li>
        <li><a href="_18">HEALING WITH HOLISTIC KINESIOLOGY</a></li>
        <li><a href="_19">UNDERSTANDING ASPERGER'S SYNDROME</a></li>
        <li><a href="_20">DAVID CORBY THE DIRECTOR OF CCM</a></li>
        <li><a href="_21">HELPING PEOPLE CREATE THEIR OWN MIRACLES</a></li>
        <li><a href="_22">MAGNESIUM AND COLLOIDAL MINERALS</a></li>
        <li><a href="_23">BRAIN ENERGETICS CHAKRAS AND NADIS</a></li>
        <li><a href="_24">KINESIOLOGY FAQ'S</a></li>'
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="25">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="26">A - Z</a></li>

 </ul>
```

and i need to add this li to ul but i need to put in the second place after the first

not nested

```
<li id="faculty">
    <a href="#">Faculty Courses </a> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">INTENSE SHORT COURSES</a><ul>
            <li><a href="_59">CRYSTAL KINESIOLOGY ONE</a></li>
            <li><a href="_60">APPLIED PHYSIOLOGY</a></li>
            <li><a href="_61">VIBRATIONAL HEALING SYSTEMS 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="_62">VIBRATIONAL HEALING SYSTEMS 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="_63">VIBRATIONAL HEALING SYSTEMS 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="_64">VIBRATIONAL HEALING SYSTEMS 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="_65">NUTRITIONAL KINESIOLOGY</a></li>
            <li><a href="_66">QUANTUM HARMONICS</a></li><li><a href="_67">CHAKRA HOLOGRAM</a></li>
            <li><a href="_68">CLINICAL APPLICATIONS OF KINESIOLOGY</a></li>
            <li><a href="_69">COUNSELLING KINESIOLOGY</a></li>
            <li><a href="_70">HARMONISING CHI FLOW</a></li>
         </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="=53">FREE INTRUCTION COURSE DAYS</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="=53_56">HOLISTIC KINESIOLOGY</a></li>
                <li><a href="=53_57">TRANSPERSONAL COUNSELLING</a></li>
                <li><a href="=53_58">SHAMMANISM &amp; TRANSFORMATIONAL MASK</a></li>
            </ul>

            </li>


            <li><a href="=50">DIPLOMA MASK AND TRADITIONAL HEALING</a></li>
            <li><a href="=43">DIPLOMA TRANSPERSONAL ART THERAPY</a></li>
            <li><a href="=42">DIPLOMA HOLISTIC KINESIOLOGY</a></li>
            <li><a href="=47">ADVANCE DIPLOMA HOLISTIC KINESIOLOGY</a></li>
            <li><a href="=48">DIPLOMA DINAMIC AND FUNCTIONAL</a></li>
            <li><a href="=49">CERTIFICATE MASK AND TRADITIONAL HEALING</a></li>
            <li><a href="=51">DIPLOMA TRANSPERSONAL COUNSELLING</a></li>
            <li><a href="=52">STUDENT CLINICS</a></li>
        </ul>

 </li>
```

please i need you help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to get a structure like:

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
    <li>Student Center ...</li>
    <li>Faculty Courses ...</li> <!-- Inserted here -->
    <li>Research ...</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
    <li>A - Z</li>
</ul>
```

then, you can use:

```
$("#faculty").insertAfter(".sf-menu > li:first");​
```

It inserts the `#faculty` list item after the first `<li>` node inside `#sf-menu`.

Learn about all DOM manipulation functions at http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Comment: Append would put it at the end. I think OP wants to place it as the second item in the list.